# Calculations with DataGridViews - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Having some problems with DGVs. Essentially, I'm checking whether `txtH1, txtH2` etc. is equal to the value within `1, i`. This value does not change. If they are equal, I want the value of `3, i` to be added to the numeric value contained within `txtP1, txtH2` etc.

However, the problem I'm running into is that the DGV is updated with the very first value, but none thereafter. So, the value of txtP1.text is not being added to the value of `3,i` on the second iteration of `i`.

For example:

`Column 1 | Column 4
John      | 5
Nancy     | 10
Bruce     | 15
Frank     | 20`

Is what it should read, given John = 2 + 3, Nancy = 5+5, Bruce = 10+5 and Frank = 15+5.

However, what I'm instead getting is:

`Column 1 | Column 3
John      | 2
Nancy     | 5
Bruce     | 10
Frank     | 15`

I hope this makes sense. If you need further clarification, let me know - but thanks in advance for your help: this beginner very much appreciates it!

```
     For i As Integer = 0 To 3

                If txtH1.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP1.Text
                ElseIf txtH2.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP2.Text
                ElseIf txtH3.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP3.Text
                ElseIf txtH4.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP4.Text
                ElseIf txtH5.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP5.Text
                ElseIf txtH6.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP6.Text
                ElseIf txtH7.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP7.Text
                ElseIf txtH8.Text = DataGridView5.Item(1, i).Value Then
                    DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value = DataGridView5.Item(3, i).Value + txtP8.Text
                End If

  Next
```

Comment: are you sure you calling the right index, because if you want column 3 it might be that this should be datagridview5.item(2,i).value

Comment: Apologies - I meant column 4. The right index is being called.